# Function assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript

As a newbie i would like to know that if we do

```
function square(x) { return x*x; }
```

and

```
var s = square;
square(4);
```

So basically the `s` is a new function in which the square function is copied? cause i am confused in this. please help.

Comment: `s is a new function in which the square function is copied?` No, now `s` references to the `square`

Comment: @Tushar i want to know like is s a new function?

Comment: No, both are pointing to the same function, Have you heard of _soft-link/shortcut_ in OS, it is the same concept

Answer (score 2):

> so basically the `s` is a new function in which the square function is copied?

No, `s` is simply another "name" with which you can refer to *the same* function.

`s === square` will be `true`, i.e. both bindings will refer to the same object.

Comment: so you mean S is like a reference to that function,,

Comment: correct @MarcAndreJiacarrini, it is a variable point to the same spot in memory

Comment: A better word for "name" might be "alias". I think that was what you were going for, right?

Answer (score 0):

S is not a new function. It is merely a pointer to the square function. They are both the same.